# Inject some service in custom DisplayFormatAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

**Hopefully this is not a duplicate!**

I am using `Autofac`.

I am struggling to inject some services with in my custom attribute called `XNameDisplayFormatAttribute` which inherits from `DisplayFormatAttribute`. The idea is that I want to get some data from database relating to current culture info for logged in user. For that I created a `SettingsService` but the problem is that I can not inject it in `XNameDisplayFormatAttribute`. I read there is not way how to inject services in attributes(*not filters*) but there are workarounds for that(*Not quite sure how!*). My custom attribute will look like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class XNameDisplayFormatAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
{
    public ISettingsService SettingsService {get;set;}
    public XNameDisplayFormatAttribute (bool applyFormatInEditMode = true) 
    {
        DataFormatString = SettingsService.GetDataFromDb();"*My format retrieved from db*";
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = applyFormatInEditMode;
    }
}
```

This is not working normally but I need something similar to this logic in order to perform get action from database.

Does anybody have any idea how this can be achievable ?

A good idea is not messing around with filters if possible, I want to keep the code clear with only appropriate attributes.

**EDIT**

I have used the code below as well but I get null value only in attributes:

```
ISettingsService settings = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISettingsService>();
```

Here is my configuration section:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    RegisterStartUp.RegisterDependecies(builder, app);
    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    //Registering model binders
    builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

    //builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
    // BUILD THE CONTAINER
    var container = builder.Build();
    // REPLACE THE MVC DEPENDENCY RESOLVER WITH AUTOFAC
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    // REGISTER WITH OWIN
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacMvc();
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Comment: Unless you are using the service locator anti-pattern there is no other way to inject services into that attribute.

Comment: @Nkosi are you referring to get the service as I am doing in **EDIT** section ?

Comment: Yes that is what I am referring to.

Comment: @Nkosi it is not working and the only place that it does not work is exactly in this attribute because in other places like in extension methods etc it works properly. I update configuration section. Do you think I need anything to add ? probably it has to do with a specific behaviour of ASP.MVC on attributes :(

Comment: have you registered `ISettingsService` with the container?

Comment: Yes sure, but it is in another method, it works in other places so there is problem on registering. `RegisterStartUp.RegisterDependecies(builder, app);`

Comment: Attribute should not depends on business logic. What is using `XNameDisplayFormatAttribute`. Could you modify this component and acts differently if your attribute is present?

Comment: It is used by a datetime property which has to be in a specific format that used has chosen, anyway due to caching policies of MVC with these attributes I am not using it at all. I choose to inherit from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` and set the logic there globally for all datetime properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design has some flaws.

You are using an attribute to implement business logic, but an attribute should normally contain only metadata, and for a good reason: the attribute is embedded into the assembly in a peculiar way, and processed differently from the rest of the classes.

The root problem of your idea is that an attribute is really meant to store (and eventually operate) on data known at compile time. An attribute is not (and, AFAICT, will never be) instantiated like the rest of the classes, so deendency injection does not apply.

What I would try: implement a class DisplayFormatManager and register it via Autofac as a singleton. This class is responsible for calling on the SettingsService and retrieving what you need.

On application startup, right after Autofac setup, you inject the DisplayFormatManager onto a static property of the `XNameDisplayFormatAttribute` class. Then hope for the best: I don't know WHEN the attribute value is going to be used.

I would search for a different path, however: if the configuration is dynamic, it should be handled via code, not via metadata, IMO. Your mileage may vary, a lot.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class XNameDisplayFormatAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
{
    public static DisplayFormatManager FormatsManager { get; set; }

    public XNameDisplayFormatAttribute(bool applyFormatInEditMode = true)
    {
        DataFormatString = FormatsManager.GetDataFromDb(_dataFormatString);
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = applyFormatInEditMode;
    }

    private string _dataFormatString;
    public new string DataFormatString
    {
        get => FormatsManager.GetDataFromDb(_dataFormatString);
        set => _dataFormatString = value;
    }
}

public class DisplayFormatManager
{
    public DisplayFormatManager(Func<ISettingsService> settingsServiceFactory)
    {
        SettingsServiceFactory = settingsServiceFactory;
    }

    public Func<ISettingsService> SettingsServiceFactory { get; }

    public string GetDataFromDb(string format)
    {
        var service = SettingsServiceFactory();
        return service.GetDataFromDb(format);
    }
}

public interface ISettingsService
{
    string GetDataFromDb(string format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject service into an action filter
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters